# Dynamically adding a view to a custom ListView item layout not working

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I wish to add a custom tailored layout for each ListView item. I have an empty linear layout in the xml layout file for ListView item layout. It has horizontal orientation.

I wish to add three FrameLayouts dynamically to above mentioned LinearLayout and set custom weight for each FrameLayout.

I found a part of the solution for it, as in the code below. Problem arises when the ListView has to be updated. ListView is initially hidden. When a certain button is pressed, ListView gets updated (hash map cleared and then filled with a new data set) and its visibility set from GONE to VISIBLE. Next thing is to loop through all the items and add designed view programmatically.

If I invoke the method `add_designed_views(null);` right after updating ListView items, the app loops through items, creates all the new views and adds them to right items. However, they are not added. I know this because of check if the item is already added, and if I invoke this method several times in a row, it will do the same each time, as if it didn't add anything at all.

Next thing that I tried is I postponed adding views dynamically by invoking the method `add_designed_views` from `onClick` of a dummy button. When I see the list has loaded (without the custom views) I press the dummy button and the custom views appear. But every 6th is missing. If I press it again, the missing ones appear. Which makes me even more confused.

It's obvious that the views can't be added immediately after changing the visibility of ListView. Probably because it takes the system some time to inflate the ListView, or it does some background task, but I couldn't find any listener or some function that tells me that it has finished loading so that I can add my views then.

Custom ListView item layout (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_border_dark_line"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="21"
        android:minHeight="40dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:minHeight="90dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/path_model"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="onClick_listItem"
            >
        <!-- Path Model. -->
        <!-- This is where I add view dynamically. -->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="10">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ic_time"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/clock"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text4_1"
                        android:textSize="14dp"
                        android:textColor="#454545"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_time" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_changes"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/change"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text4_2"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#454545"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_changes"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_cost"
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/coins"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text4_3"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#454545"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_cost"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="10">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="21"
        android:minHeight="38dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

add_designed_views method (Java):

```
public void add_designed_views(View view)
{
    for(int i=0; i<hashmap_search_results_list.size(); i++)
    {
        /* Check if it is already added. We have to check,
           because we run it twice in consecutive order. */
        LinearLayout listView_item = (LinearLayout)getViewByPosition(i, listView_search_results);
        View middle_ground = ((ViewGroup) listView_item).getChildAt(1);

        LinearLayout path_model = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) middle_ground).getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout already_added_ll_path = (LinearLayout)((ViewGroup)path_model).getChildAt(0);
        if(already_added_ll_path != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Already has linear layout: " + hashmap_search_results_list.get(i).get("latest_departure_time"));
            continue;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Doing: " + hashmap_search_results_list.get(i).get("latest_departure_time"));

        Search_Result_Item result_item = (Search_Result_Item)search_results_list.get(i);

        /* How to access each view at each item position in list view. */
        //LinearLayout listView_item = (LinearLayout) getViewByPosition(i, listView_search_results);
        //View middle_ground = ((ViewGroup) listView_item).getChildAt(1);
        //LinearLayout path_model = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) middle_ground).getChildAt(0);

        /* Setting the proportions of lines regarding walking time and riding time. */
        HrMin hrmin_walking_to_entrance_time = result_item.walking_to_entrance_time();
        HrMin hrmin_riding_time = result_item.travel_time();
        HrMin hrmin_walking_from_exit_time = result_item.walking_from_exit_time();

        int int_walking_to_entrance_time = hrmin_get_minutes(hrmin_walking_to_entrance_time);
        int int_riding_time = hrmin_get_minutes(hrmin_riding_time);
        int int_walking_from_exit_time = hrmin_get_minutes(hrmin_walking_from_exit_time);
        int total = int_walking_to_entrance_time +
                int_riding_time +
                int_walking_from_exit_time;

        float weight_walking_to_entrance = (float)int_walking_to_entrance_time/total;
        float weight_bus_ride = (float)int_riding_time/total;
        float weight_walking_from_exit = (float)int_walking_from_exit_time/total;

        /* How to add a new layout, view to existing layout. */
        LinearLayout ll_path = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        /* Pedestrian image. */
        ImageView pedestrian = new ImageView(this);
        pedestrian.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.runner_rnd));

        int dimensionInPixel = 16;
        int dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams pedestrian_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                dimensionInDp,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        pedestrian.setLayoutParams(pedestrian_params);

        /* Gray Line. */
        FrameLayout frameLayout_pedestrian_container = new FrameLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams frame_layout_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                weight_walking_to_entrance);

        View gray_line = new View(this);
        gray_line.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.horizontal_gray_line));

        dimensionInPixel = 4;
        dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams gray_line_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        gray_line.setLayoutParams(gray_line_params);

        frameLayout_pedestrian_container.addView(gray_line);
        frameLayout_pedestrian_container.addView(pedestrian);
        frameLayout_pedestrian_container.setLayoutParams(frame_layout_params);
        ll_path.addView(frameLayout_pedestrian_container);

        /* Bus image. */
        FrameLayout frameLayout_bus_container = new FrameLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams frame_layout_bus_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                weight_bus_ride);

        ImageView bus = new ImageView(this);
        bus.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bus_rnd));

        dimensionInPixel = 17;
        dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams bus_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                dimensionInDp,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        bus.setLayoutParams(bus_params);

        /* Green line. */
        View green_line = new View(this);
        green_line.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.horizontal_green_line));

        dimensionInPixel = 4;
        dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams green_line_params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        green_line.setLayoutParams(green_line_params);

        frameLayout_bus_container.addView(green_line);
        frameLayout_bus_container.addView(bus);
        frameLayout_bus_container.setLayoutParams(frame_layout_bus_params);
        ll_path.addView(frameLayout_bus_container);

        /* Walking from exit path. */
        ImageView pedestrian2 = new ImageView(this);
        pedestrian2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.runner_rnd));

        dimensionInPixel = 16;
        dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams pedestrian_params2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                dimensionInDp,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        pedestrian2.setLayoutParams(pedestrian_params2);

        /* Gray Line. */
        FrameLayout frameLayout_pedestrian_container2 = new FrameLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams frame_layout_params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                weight_walking_from_exit);

        View gray_line2 = new View(this);
        gray_line2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.horizontal_gray_line));

        dimensionInPixel = 4;
        dimensionInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dimensionInPixel, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams gray_line_params2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                dimensionInDp,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        gray_line2.setLayoutParams(gray_line_params2);

        frameLayout_pedestrian_container2.addView(gray_line2);
        frameLayout_pedestrian_container2.addView(pedestrian2);
        frameLayout_pedestrian_container2.setLayoutParams(frame_layout_params2);
        ll_path.addView(frameLayout_pedestrian_container2);


        ll_path.setLayoutParams(params);
        ll_path.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        path_model.addView(ll_path);
    }
}
```

Part where I update the ListView and show it:

```
search_results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

ListView is a child of two layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingTop="140dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:onClick="onClick_nothing">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/search_options_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped is `Handler.postDelayed()`:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            add_designed_views (null);
        }
    }, 300);
```

This function delays method call for 300 mS. Programmatically added layouts are visible. But, still every 6th is missing. They also appear after I touch any of the items.

Comment: this is a workaround and it doesn't solve the issue completely. Is this some UI rendering boundary that I hit upon?